# Access denied to the path While writing a file in windows 7 using vb.net windows application

Tags: vb.net

I am having a windows application. That downloads files from server and write into the local directory. It works fine. When we try the same appliication in Windows 7. IT shows an error Access to the path denied (While writing to the local directory).  Any one please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be UAC issue. Try to start the program as Administrator.

just FYI, to start the program as Administrator: right-click on the program -> click on 'Run as Administrator'

You may also see this: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691(WS.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691%28WS.10%29.aspx)
to set us your UAC for your system.